# Using JavaScript to update radio button within table cell

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am trying to use JavaScript to update the checked status of a radio button on a site managed by a large company.  Here’s the issue – the page has duplicate IDs and names for the two related radio buttons and they reside in the cell of a row of an unnamed table.  I want to select the first one.  Thanks for any help.

Below is the basic html

```
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img alt='spacer' src='../Images/blank.gif' width='10' height='1' border='0' />
        </td>
        <td id='A-Q1_0200-1' valign='top'>
            <font size='-1'>
                <input type='radio' name='Q1_0200' id='Q1_0200' value='1' onclick='FormChanged()'
                class='bodyInput' />
            </font>
        </td>
        <td colspan='1' valign='top' id='A-Q1_0200-1-T'>
            <font size='-1'>
                &nbsp;Yes
            </font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <font size='-1'>
                &nbsp;
            </font>
        </td>
        <td id='A-Q1_0200-2' valign='top'>
            <font size='-1'>
                <input type='radio' name='Q1_0200' id='Q1_0200' value='2' checked='checked' onclick='FormChanged()'
                class='bodyInput' />
            </font>
        </td>
        <td colspan='1' valign='top' id='A-Q1_0200-2-T'>
            <font size='-1'>
                &nbsp;No
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below are the various javascript examples I’ve tried to update the radio to select the first radio option.

```
    document.getElementById('A-Q1_0200-1').Q1_0201.checked='checked'; 

    document.getElementById('A-Q1_0200-1').radio[0].checked=TRUE;

    document.getElementById('Q1_0200').checked=TRUE

    document.getElementById('Q1_0200').checked=’TRUE
```

Comment: I am trying to change the first radio element from not checked to 'checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate IDs and expect `getElementById()` to work. ID means "identity" and each ID needs to be unique. That is why your 3rd and 4th examples failed.

The following code will select the parent `<td>` by it's id, then it will select the first descendant `input` and set the `checked` property.

```
document.getElementById('A-Q1_0200-1').getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = "checked";
```

Comment: Thanks - this makes perfect sense.  I tried it and it did not work, however.  Also, what determines whether to use true or 'checked' at the end?  (I tried both)

Comment: Jesse, I tried it outside of my IDE - using Firebug (as another responder below suggested).  It works - thank you.  The only issue is that while it changes the radio button to "checked", it does not open the related cascading text fields based on that selection.  Perhaps I have to initiate something else for that.

Comment: Got it - just needed to run a function behind the other script.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/rr2Zk/).  This would allow you to select the first element of type radio.

One way to do it is use `getElementsByTagName` and check for the first occurrence of type radio, but ID should be unique.  Seems like it's out of your control:

```
var myInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i=0; i<myInput.length; i++){
    if(myInput[i].type == 'radio'){
         console.log(myInput[i]);
         break;
    }
}
```

The console.log would give you the following element:

```
<input type=​"radio" name=​"Q1_0200" id=​"Q1_0200" value=​"1" onclick=​"FormChanged()​" class=​"bodyInput">​
```

and from there on you can set the selected element's checked to true: `myInput[i].checked = true;` or `myInput[i].checked = 'checked';`

Comment: Thanks - I will test this option out as well.  Although I wouldn't think it would make a difference, I am testing this through Apple xCode, through an iOS app I'm developing.  Again all the other JS on the page (textfield updating) works fine.  Is there another tool I could use to test this same js on someone else's website to see if it works?  (e.g., Aptana or another tool)

Comment: @user you can use chrome's developer tool or firefox's firebug to debug js

Comment: @user what do you mean text fields don't appear? do you have an event listener attached to the radio button?

Answer (score 0):

getElementById will return you the first found element. And if you want to check it you need to do: `document.getElementById('Q1_0200').checked = 'checked';`

Comment: is right. This will work for your situation, just pray that the order of the html doesn't change on you.

Comment: Thanks for your response - this did not work for me however.  Could any CSS or other script somewhere be causing radio buttons to not be accessible via js?  I have been able to select and update text fields with no problem.

Comment: @user689852 You could have another element with id=Q1_0200 somewhere that's not a radio input element? Provide more information on why/what failed. Firebug and Chrome Developer Tools are great tools for debugging your code.